# CAS 3.5.2 - Login workflow Customization

Tags: cas

I am using CAS 3.5.2. I have a requirement to send some details to a CAPTCHA third party before authentication and show captcha in login screen if required. How do i customize / override the class that handles the login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i customize / override the class that handles the login?

The class that handles the login attempt is a Spring Webflow action that is `AuthenticationViaFormAction.java` and its `submit` method. Assuming you are using a CAS overlay, you can create the folder structure `src/main/java/org/jasig/cas/web/flow/` in the root directory of your overlay, and then copy that Java file in there by its exact name [from here](https://github.com/apereo/cas/blob/3.6.x/cas-server-core/src/main/java/org/jasig/cas/web/flow/AuthenticationViaFormAction.java). Then customize the class, build and repackage and at runtime, your compiled version of the class will be used instead of the one that ships with CAS by default.

To make sure the build is successful, you will need to make sure that,

- Your maven overlay contains the maven compiler plugin
- Your maven overlay contains all other dependencies that would be required at compile-time to compile the new overlaid class.

This class is automatically auto-wired into the Spring Webflow definition as a Spring Bean, and so all you need to do is to make sure the build and repackaging of it is successful.

Comment: Thanks much. Will try this out and let you know.

Comment: I am able to override AuthenticationViaFormAction.java successfully. How do i redirect to Login page again without changing the service URL. In the FormAction class, i am invoking catcha service and captcha determines if a captcha is neeeded for the user id. If the captcha is needed, i will have to get back to the login page and show the catcha. I need help in understanding how to redirect to login keeping the service URL as such and carry the catcha text back to login screen.